# Locust web interface: AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'is_xhr'

Tags: locust

Facing an issue with the locust web interface in localhost "localhost:8089" but after launching the web interface an error is coming and even logs are not showing also.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kuldeep.yadav/Documents/locustTutorial/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gevent/pywsgi.py", line 999, in handle_one_response
    self.run_application()
  File "/Users/kuldeep.yadav/Documents/locustTutorial/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gevent/pywsgi.py", line 945, in run_application
    self.result = self.application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/Users/kuldeep.yadav/Documents/locustTutorial/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/kuldeep.yadav/Documents/locustTutorial/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/Users/kuldeep.yadav/Documents/locustTutorial/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/kuldeep.yadav/Documents/locustTutorial/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/kuldeep.yadav/Documents/locustTutorial/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/kuldeep.yadav/Documents/locustTutorial/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/kuldeep.yadav/Documents/locustTutorial/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/kuldeep.yadav/Documents/locustTutorial/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/kuldeep.yadav/Documents/locustTutorial/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/kuldeep.yadav/Documents/locustTutorial/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/kuldeep.yadav/Documents/locustTutorial/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/locust/web.py", line 366, in wrapper
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kuldeep.yadav/Documents/locustTutorial/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/locust/util/cache.py", line 22, in wrapper
    cache["result"] = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kuldeep.yadav/Documents/locustTutorial/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/locust/web.py", line 301, in request_stats
    return jsonify(report)
  File "/Users/kuldeep.yadav/Documents/locustTutorial/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/json.py", line 251, in jsonify
    if current_app.config['JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR'] and not request.is_xhr:
  File "/Users/kuldeep.yadav/Documents/locustTutorial/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 347, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'is_xhr'
2021-10-22T15:58:55Z {'REMOTE_ADDR': '::ffff:127.0.0.1', 'REMOTE_PORT': '50803', 'HTTP_HOST': 'localhost:8089', (hidden keys: 28)} failed with AttributeError
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any reference in Locust or Flask to `is_xhr`. I see some really really really old references to that in werkzeug. Running really old packages on new versions of Python (3.9 that it looks like you're using) is likely to have many things be broken. Check the version of Locust you're running:

`locust --version`

Current version is 2.4.1. If you're not running that, upgrade your Locust install:

`pip install --upgrade locust`

Then try running Locust again.